# Does chunking incorporate asynchronous execution? How to stream chunks asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, playframework-2.0, chunking

In the Play Documentation [Chunks are introduced](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaStream) as a solution to "streaming content". I am unsure whether streaming content can be produced slowly without blocking the HTTP thread or if I must separately make the convert the Chunks to an AsyncResult by changing (`sc` is declared as `Chunks`):

```
return ok(sc);
```

to:

```
return async(play.libs.Akka.future(new Callable<Result>() {
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        return ok(sc);
    }
}));
```

When using the second solution, the chunks aren't appearing incrementally in the browser, and I wanted them to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to wrap your result in `async` if your computation happens in a `Promise` (`Future` in 2.1), e.g. when using an Akka actor. The result type is then `AsyncResult`.

Since `Chunks` (defined in `play.mvc.Results.java`) internally uses an `Enumerator` that pushes the callback's content to an `Iteratee`, it *should* be non-blocking.

[image]